# Xcode - Initial constraints changes when viewing a container view for the first time

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

I have a main view controller with a container which includes a table view controller. In the main view controller, the container is placed using constraints in each direction but when the main view controller appears for the first time, it does not follow the constraints.

However, when I switch the other view ("Uppladdning") and then back to the main view, the container is displayed correctly.

[image: This is the view in the Storyboard.]
[image: This is how it looks in the simulator, as you can see, the bottom part stretches outside of the screen.]
[image: And here's the settings for my container view in the main view controller.]

Comment: Are you sure that the container view is not following constraints? Can it be the table view ?

Comment: I was thinking that as well, but because it displays correctly when I return to the view, even though the container content is the same, I feel it doesn't have anything to do with the table view.

Answer (score 0):

All right, so I found a temporary solution to my problem.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if (firstTimeDisplay)! {
        self.certificateListViewContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 9, y: 9, width: self.view.bounds.width - 18, height: self.view.bounds.height - 52)
    }
}
```

That is, I manually change the frame size of the container when it is displayed for the first time, using a boolean **var firstTimeDisplay**. Not an elegant solution, but it will do at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Set a background color for your container view and try it again. This will help you figure out whether constraints on your container view or table view is not working.

Ideally, nothing should be triggered if you are just switching back to a view controller from another tab in a tab bar controller or from a segue. So put a break point to methods like an unwind method, `prepareForSegue` and see what get changed when you switch back. Then you will find out why your constraints start working on the second time.